# Getting an error when running Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to Ruby on Rails and just trying to play around. I'm trying to run the rails server and I cannot get it to start because I get the following error:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:40:in `<module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper (NameError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.2/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.2/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:7:in `<class:Template>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:6:in `<module:WebConsole>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console.rb:12:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
        from C:/wamp/www/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a brand new repo? you just run `rails generate scaffod` `rails migrate`, and then `rails server?`, or anything else have you done with this repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `bundle install` in your command line. If that isn't it, please check back in with the results from your command line and we can try to troubleshoot the problem from there.

Good luck.

Comment: So yes I had run bundle install and I did it again for good measure and it runs just fine. but when I when do "rails server" in the command line I get the error I put in my question.

Comment: So, a while back I ran into a similar problem. Something I found out was that in Rails, the "rails server" command should work out the box unless there was a failed or incomplete install. This was the case in my circumstance. Ultimately I just did a complete uninstall/reinstall of Rails as it was much easier than troubleshooting my previous Rails install.

With that said, when did you install Rails? Has "rails server" ever worked or is this a new thing? Honestly, sometimes the easiest way to deal with malfunctions like this is to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: If you decide to uninstall/reinstall rails, make sure you do it thoroughly and reinstall with RVM.

Comment: OK I'm going to give this question a day or two and if I don't get the answer I need I'll reinstall. If it works you got the answer bro. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, best of luck!

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem yet? If you would like me to run you through a thorough uninstall process, I can also do that. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you bundled from the command prompt?

```
bundle install
```

Is this the error you get when running server? What appears on your localhost:3000?

Comment: Yes, this is the error I get when I try to run: rails server.
localhost:3000 shows unable to connect which makes sense since the web server isn't running.